# C# override an abstract method with base classes with a method using derived classes

Tags: c#, interface, abstract, derived-class, implements

Can't seem to find a solution, and don't see why this is not possible:

(this first line of code does not seem to want to format properly on my browser)

```
namespace Definitions
{
    public interface iCore
    {
        public ChannelBase GetChannel(UrlBase url);
    }

    public abstract class Core : iCore
    {
        public abstract ChannelBase GetChannel(UrlBase url);
    }

    public class ChannelBase
    {
        public ChannelBase(iCore core) 
        { }
    }

    public class UrlBase
    {
        public UrlBase(iCore core) 
        { }
    }
}

namespace Processing
{
    /// Error Thrown:
    //Severity Code    Description Project File Line    Suppression State
    //Error CS0534  'MyCore' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Core.GetChannel(UrlBase)'


    public class MyCore : Definitions.Core
    {
        /// It suggests this Implementation:
        //public override Definitions.ChannelBase GetChannel(Definitions.UrlBase url) { }

        /// I need this to work, but how ?
        public override MyChannel GetChannel(MyUrl url) 
        { 
             /// This is where i would really need that MyUrl.MyExtraPropertyIneed !
            return null; 
        }
    }

    public class MyChannel : Definitions.ChannelBase
    {
        public MyChannel(MyCore core) : base(core) 
        { }
    }

    public class MyUrl : Definitions.UrlBase
    {
        public MyUrl(MyCore core)  : base(core)
        {
            MyExtraPropertyIneed = "I NEED this property"
        }
        
        public string MyExtraPropertyIneed { get; private set; }
        // PS this is a basic example, but I really can't have this property in the base class, the derived class gets info from online and does "stuff"
    }
}
```

"public override MyChannel GetChannel(MyUrl url)" always throws error "'MyCore' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Core.GetChannel(UrlBase)'"

How would one go about solving this ?

Expected the derived classes to be accepted.

Mind you, for the example I used different namespaces, but in reality each namespace is a separate project.

Comment: Sounds like you need to introduce generics. `Core<T> where T:UrlBase{... GetChannel(T url) ...}` or just a simple `if (url is MyUrl myUrl) ...`

Comment: You wouldn't be able to show me that in code snippet using the example code I provided ?

Comment: The best you can do (with newer versions of c#) is to change the return type only, a feature called Covariant returns. You cannot however, change the parameter types. You'd need to resort to generics, or by using method hiding and delegating to the virtual method, likely with casting.

Comment: `Expected the derived classes to be accepted` why? That is not how C# works.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the signature of `GetChannel()` like this.

```
public override ChannelBase GetChannel(UrlBase url)
    {
        // implementation
        return new MyChannel(this);
    }
```

Comment: It's the UrlBase that is the biggest problem .. I need the extra properties and functions from the derrived class.
Same goes vor its return ChannelBase, that is gonna be used as a parameter in another function which will be expecting the "MyChannel" derribed class which has extra parameters and functions. Woulnd't passing it as a return value like this just end me up with the stripped ChannelBase later on again ?

Comment: Looks like I'm gonna have to merge the 2 Projects into one..
Amd have Structure and Functionality mixed together

Answer (score 0):

Function overriding does not allow the the signature to be different. If you want the subclass to be returned, probably have the same signature as abstract method, but return subclass instance and then, and cast to subclass in the caller of the method.

```
public override ChannelBase GetChannel(UrlBase url) 
{ 
    return new MyChannel(); 
}

In the caller method,

var obj = new MyCore().GetChannel();
```

This should work.

Below is the update code.

```
public class ChannelBase
    {
        public ChannelBase(ICore core)
        { }
    }

    public class MyChannel : ChannelBase
    {
        public MyChannel(MyCore core) : base(core)
        { }
    }

public class UrlBase
    {
        public UrlBase(ICore core)
        { }
    }

    public class MyUrl :UrlBase
    {
        public MyUrl(MyCore core) : base(core)
        {
            MyExtraPropertyIneed = "I NEED this property";
        }

        public string MyExtraPropertyIneed { get; private set; }
        // PS this is a basic example, but i really can't have this property in the base class, the derived class gets info from online and does "stuff"
    }

    public interface ICore
    {
        public ChannelBase GetChannel(UrlBase url);
    }

    public abstract class Core : ICore
    {
        public abstract ChannelBase GetChannel(UrlBase url);
    }

    public class MyCore : Core
    {
        /// It suggests this Implementation:
        //public override Definitions.ChannelBase GetChannel(Definitions.UrlBase url) { }

        /// I need this to work, but how ?
        public override MyChannel GetChannel(UrlBase url)
        {
            /// This is where i would really need that MyUrl.MyExtraPropertyIneed !
            var testString = ((MyUrl)url).MyExtraPropertyIneed;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And, from where you are instantiating new MyCore, you can use below:

```
var mycore = new MyCore().GetChannel(new MyUrl(null));
```

Basically, you type cast the url object to the subclass (MyUrl)

Comment: Well,.. yes and no. Thanks for the replies.
What i forgot to mention is that the Base Classes have like all basic generic stuff, and My Derrived classes have some extra properties and functioms and such.
I'll update the code in post in a minute.
But if I'm getting UrlBase as input, I am missing all the extra stuff !

Comment: Based on further details you provided, I have updated the code above. @DirkBourgeois